# Removing a radius clause in my dbGeography linq-to-entity statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, dbgeography

How can I remove the 'radius' in my linq-to-entity statement so that it doesn't limit the search to the radius?

FYI - I want my query to search for names that start with the 'term' and search  outward starting with the names that are closest to the location points, but not limiting it to a radius

```
DbGeography location = DbGeography.FromText("POINT(" + longitude.ToString() + " " + latitude.ToString() + ")");
            int radius = (50 * 5280); // 50 miles

            var namesList = (from N in dbContext.Profiles
                             where N.FullName.StartsWith(term) 
                             && N.LocationPoints.Distance(location) <= radius
                             orderby N.LocationPoints.Distance(location) ascending
                             select new ProfileNameSearch {
                                 label = N.FullName + " - " + N.Location,
                                 value = N.FullName,
                                 location = N.LocationPoints.Latitude.ToString() + "," + N.LocationPoints.Longitude.ToString()
                             }).Take(10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the line

&& N.LocationPoints.Distance(location) <= radius

Comment: but I want the search to start at the location and move outward

Comment: Isn't that done with the order by N.LocationPoints.Distance(location)